# Position of lights in blinn light model

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, opengl-3, fragment-shader

I have implemented Blinn-Phong shading in my fragment shader to calculate the lighting of each fragment with multiple lights. The computation seems to be all good except for one part. My directional light is computed correctly but my position light is not.

Pictures talk more than word so:

*Wrong light positions:*

[image: first screen showing the misplacement of the light]

The shader works like this:

I update the light array with their positions in world space. And then for each object, I upload their material information and draw them using this fragment shader to get the correct color. The vertex shader's only task (regarding lighting) is to pass on normals for the fragment. All my computation are done in world space.

I already checked the position of each light and they are correct. Which is why I came here. I think I made a mistake when I compute the cosine of the incident angle but I don't know where.

Here is the code of my fragment shader:

**Edit :** I corrected some mistakes with the nice help of Nico Schertler, here is the new code with both fragment and vertex shader

**Edit 2 :** After another round of check, it was in fact not a misplaced light position. But an error in the computation of dot vector between the normal and the light direction.

**Fragment Shader**

```
#version 330 compatibility

struct light {
   vec4 position; // position.w indicates if it's a direction or point lighting
   vec3 diffuse; // diffuse color of the light
   vec3 specular; // specular color of the light
   float attenuation; // attenuation of the light
};
struct material {
   vec3 diffuse;
   vec3 specular;
   vec3 ambient;
   float shininess;
};

uniform material objMaterial;
uniform light lights[9];
uniform int nbLight;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix; // Matrix to view coordinate
uniform mat4 viewInvMatrix; // invert view matrix to find the position of the viewer

in vec3 worldNormal; // normal in worldspace
in vec3 position; // position in worldspace

vec3 ambiant = vec3(0.2,0.2,0.2);

void main()
{
   int i;
   vec3 viewDirection = normalize((viewInvMatrix * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) - vec4(position, 1.)).xyz);
   vec3 lightDirection, lightPositon;
   vec3 normalizeWorldNormal = normalize(worldNormal);
   float attenuation; 
   vec3 totalLight = ambiant * objMaterial.ambient;
   float cosAngIncidence;
   float blinnTerm;

   for(i=0; i<9; i=i+1){
      if(i < nbLight){
         lightPositon = lights[i].position.xyz;
         if (0.0 == lights[i].position.w) // directional light?
         {
            attenuation = 1.0; // no attenuation
            lightDirection = normalize(lightPositon);
         }
         else // point light
         {
            vec3 positionToLightSource = lightPositon - position;
            lightDirection = normalize(positionToLightSource);
            float dis = length(positionToLightSource);
            attenuation = 1.0 / (lights[i].attenuation * dis);
         }
         cosAngIncidence = dot(normalizeWorldNormal, lightDirection);
         cosAngIncidence = clamp(cosAngIncidence, 0, 1);

         vec3 halfAngle = normalize(lightDirection + viewDirection);
         blinnTerm = dot(normalizeWorldNormal, halfAngle);
         blinnTerm = clamp(blinnTerm, 0, 1);
         blinnTerm = cosAngIncidence != 0.0 ? blinnTerm : 0.0;
         blinnTerm = pow(blinnTerm, objMaterial.shininess*5);

         totalLight = totalLight
            + (lights[i].diffuse * objMaterial.diffuse * attenuation * cosAngIncidence)
            + (lights[i].specular * objMaterial.specular * attenuation * blinnTerm);
      }
   }
   gl_FragColor = vec4(totalLight.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

**Vertex Shader**

```
#version 330 compatibility

layout(location=0) in vec3 vx_pos;
layout(location=1) in vec3 vx_nor;
layout(location=3) in vec3 vx_col;

uniform mat4 modelMatrix; // Matrix to world coordinate
uniform mat4 normalInvTransMatrix; // Matrix for normal in world coordinate
uniform mat4 viewMatrix; // Matrix to view coordinate
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix; // Matrix to projection coordinate

out vec3 worldNormal; 
out vec3 position;

void main() {
   gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(vx_pos,1.0);
   worldNormal = vec3(normalInvTransMatrix * vec4(vx_nor, 0.));
   position = vec3(modelMatrix * vec4(vx_pos,0.)); 
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't handle `lightDirection` and `positionToLightSource` as a `vec4`. Do the w-clip on `lights[i].position` and use the `vec3` from then on. Normalizing a `vec4` won't result in the correct direction. Same for `worldNormal` and `position`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (and for correcting my broken english) and for the normalizing vec4 "issue". But it did not solve the main problem.

Comment: Could you update the code in your question?

Comment: Here it is, I add the vertex shader to see if I've done it right too.